# How does this Python memory optimization work?

Tags: python, memory

OpenAI has published a set of Machine Learning/Reinforcement Learning environments called 'Open AI Gym'. Some of the environments are image based, and as such can potentially have a very large memory footprint when used with algorithms that store 100 000s or millions of frames worth of environment observations.

While poking around in their reference implementation of DeepQ Learning I found a pair of classes, [`LazyFrameStack`](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/atari_wrappers.py#L146) and [`LazyFrames`](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/atari_wrappers.py#L186) that claim to "ensure that common frames between the observations are only stored once... to optimize memory usage which can be huge for DQN's 1M frames replay buffers."

In the reference implementation, the DeepQ agent gets frames stacked together in groups of four, which are then put into the replay buffer. Having looked at the implementation of both classes, it's not obvious to me how these save memory -- if anything, because `LazyFrames` is basically a container object around a set of four `numpy` arrays, shouldn't a `LazyFrame` have a larger memory footprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, objects are passed as reference. That means even though a LazyFrame object might be a list of extremely big numpy arrays, the size of that LazyFrame object itself is small, since it only stores the reference to the `np.ndarray`s. In other words, you can think of LazyFrame just pointing to the `np.ndarray` data, and not actually storing each copy of the individual array within itself.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((2,3))
b = np.ones((2,3))
X = [a, b]

print(X)
>>> [array([[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]]),
     array([[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]])]

X_stacked = np.stack(X)

print(X_stacked)
>>> array([[[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]],

           [[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]]])

a[0] = 2
print(X)
>>> [array([[2., 2., 2.],
            [1., 1., 1.]]),
     array([[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]])]

print(X_stacked)
>>> array([[[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]],

           [[1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

As you can see here, `X` (which is a list of arrays) stores only the reference to `a` and `b`, thus when we do `a[0] = 2`, the change can be seen by printing `X`. But once you stack the arrays, you actually create a new array with that much memory.

To address your "how does it save memory" question a bit more directly, here's an example.

```
import sys

a = np.random.randn(210, 160, 3)
b = np.random.randn(210, 160, 3)

X = [a,b]
X_stacked = np.stack(X)

print(sys.getsizeof(X))
>>> 80

print(sys.getsizeof(X_stacked))
>>> 1612944
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you. : )